# PHP OOP After migration from PHP5.6 to 7.2 mysql INSERT query doesn't work anymore

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm quite new to PHP OOP. But after migration from 5.6 to PHP7.2 and MSQL to MSQLi the INSERT query does not work anymore.

**ClassDBCon.inc.php**

```
class Dbh {
  private $dbhost;
  private $dbuser;
  private $dbpass;
  private $dbname;

  protected function connect() {
    $this->dbhost = "127.0.0.1:3307";
    $this->dbuser = "root";
    $this->dbpass = "mypassword";
    $this->dbname = "mydatabase";

    $conn = new mysqli($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass, $this->dbname);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "failed to connect to mysql:" . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    return $conn;
  }

}
```

**ClassProjects.inc.php**

```
    class Projects extends Dbh{

        public function CreateNewProject($projectnr,$projectname,$iprange,$language,$pm,$hwe,$swe,$amount_cpu,$amount_hmi) {

            //Add new project
            $sql = $this->connect()->query("INSERT INTO tbl_projects(no,name,status,ip,language,pm,hwe,swe,amount_cpu,amount_hmi)
            VALUES('$projectnr','$projectname','1','$iprange','$language','$pm','$hwe','$swe','$amount_cpu','$amount_hmi')");

            MsgBox("Project successfully created");

            return $sql;
        }
}
```

In the same ClassProjects i use the SELECT and UPDATE query and thats works fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I do notice that you're mixing the procedural style and object oriented style of using mysqli, for example when you use [`mysqli_connect_errno` instead of `$conn->connect_errno`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-errno.php). I don't think that's the cause, but it's generally considered bad practise and may cause confusion.

Comment: As for the error, there is no error checking at all around the query. And also, you input the values straight into the query without using bind parameters or (seemingly) even without escaping the values. Make sure to check the result of `->query`, check for error messages related to that, and check the generated SQL to verify what is wrong. For us it's virtually impossible to tell without having that information.

Comment: Where are you calling the function `CreateNewProject`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing oop and procedural versions together and that is the reason why it does not work.

Do get it to work you need to write it like this :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_projects(no,name,status,ip,language,pm,hwe,swe,amount_cpu,amount_hmi)
        VALUES('$projectnr','$projectname','1','$iprange','$language','$pm','$hwe','$swe','$amount_cpu','$amount_hmi')";

$this->connect()->query($sql);
```

Edit:

If you want to store a notification add it into if statement like this instead:

```
if($this->connect()->query($sql) {
    MsgBox("Project successfully created");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the result of the query is still 0

Comment: Can you var_dump($sql): Might be that you are missing a variable. After var dump copy the result and run it as sql query in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Thats a great way for debugging! I was not aware of the var_dump() function. After adding it in mysql it gave me the following message: Error
SQL query:

#1364 - Field 'workshop' doesn't have a default value. I also upgraded from MariaDB5 to MariaDB10, maybe MariaDB10 does not accept it anymore?

Comment: It seems that you are missing a value. If your table has more fields which are required by insert and are not assigned a default value (for instance id which is auto incerement or default value assigned  in database) then you need to include those in your query as well.

Comment: Yes you can. Add it like this.
if($this->connect()->query($sql) {
    MsgBox("Project successfully created");
} else {
   echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $this->connect()->error;
}

Comment: Your right Chris, thanks for your help! But is it possible to get this message with mysqli_error (or something similar)?